# Integração de sistema escolar com o moodle

Tags: moodle

Pessoal há uns três dias estou tentando fazer uma sincronização de dados de um sistema escolar com o moodle, mas está bem enroscado.

Tenho um sistema escolar em um servidor linux e o moodle instalado em outro servidor. No banco de dados do servidor do sistema escolar foi criado um usuário para a permissão de visualização apenas das views que serão importadas para o moodle.

Já foi realizada as configurações em "Administração do site->plugins->autenticação->use um banco de dados externo" e também em "Administração do site->plugins->inscrição->use um banco de dados externo".

Também já rodei o script no servidor: "/usr/bin/php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php"

Também já rodei isso no browser: "http://url.of.your/moodle/admin/cron.php"

Versão do moodle: 2.5.1

Servidor com moodle instalado: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Servidor com sistema escolar instalado: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Alguém aí trabalha com o moodle que possa me dar uma ajudinha?

Na verdade sou um novato com o moodle.